# How to create custom django validation for authentication

Tags: django

Hi everyone) I'm new in Django. I need to do a really simple validation for sign in form. In my app can sign in only one user, with a specific username and password, for example, "my_username" and "my_password". And superuser can't sign in. I don't know do I even need a table in a database for only one user?

By now I write a simple login form with django.contrib.auth.views LoginView and this work, but for everyone who is in database and superuser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the django admin page create a new user.

Then if you want to allow only this user in some view just add this decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(lambda user: user.username == 'allowed_username')
def my_view(request):
    # your code
```